# Pass internalIpOnly to projects.regions.clusters.create through gcloud

Tags: gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

GceClusterConfig object has property [internalIpOnly](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.clusters#GceClusterConfig), but there is no clear documentation on how to specify that flag through [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create). Is there a way to pass that property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That feature was first released in [gcloud beta dataproc clusters create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/dataproc/clusters/create) where you can use the `--no-address` flag to turn that on. The feature recently became General Availability, and should be making it into the main `gcloud dataproc clusters create` any moment now (it's possible if you run `gcloud components update` you'll get the flag in the non-beta branch even though the public documentation hasn't been updated to reflect it yet).